# Accessing the live stream of an IP camera (Dlink 930l) with authentication on Android

Tags: android, ip-camera

I have an IPCamera (Dlink DCS930l) connected to a network which requires authentication to access the stream.

Are there any Android libraries or frameworks that have the functionality to access an authenticated network stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do something similar with a GoPro via Wifi connection.

**Method 1:** This can be achieved using OpenCV. Based on the type of authentication used, you will need to specify the corresponding protocol, username and password when you provide the IP to access the camera. The syntax required to open the camera stream [using OpenCV is provided here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/133/how-do-i-access-an-ip-camera/) (1).

You will need to use [OpenCV for Android](https://opencv.org/platforms/android/) and JNI bindings to the native C++ OpenCV API. Some [sample applications here](https://opencv.org/platforms/android/opencv4android-samples.html) demonstrate how to make calls to the native API in an Android project.

*xuchong* has developed a [sample Android application](https://github.com/xuchong/android-opencv-ffmpeg) demonstrating how to read an mp4 file natively via OpenCV on Android. Update the video path in the `MainActivity.java` `OnCreate()` method to the IP camera feed with the syntax from (1) to read from a camera requiring authentication.

**Method 2:** [An example application](https://github.com/niqdev/ipcam-view) demonstrating an alternative method that does not use OpenCV but instead uses the mjpeg library can be found here.

**Method 3:** Using just `VideoView`, assuming you have a http stream using Basic Auth for authentication, you can set headers when you provide the URI link in the following way:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>(1);
byte[] toEncrypt = (username + ":" + password).getBytes();
String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(toEncrypt, Base64.DEFAULT);
final String auth = "Basic " + encoded;
params.put("Authorization", auth);
Log.e(TAG, "Params Encode: " + params);
myVideoView.setVideoURI(vidAddress, params);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. is there any simpler way to achieve that. like using video view or surface view

Comment: This Android project demonstrates how to authenticate and access an IP camera without OpenCV but depends on mjpeg library: https://github.com/niqdev/ipcam-view

Comment: Here is a very simple method  to stream video to Android through RSTP: https://gist.github.com/iamcxa/89f4a75d8dce3aea6a3bc4e0819043a4, You can try to authenticate to the stream using the following format : rstp://<username:password>@<ip_address> . However I have not seen this documented so it is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: Glad to help. Please vote on my post +1 if it was useful  :).

Comment: sorry bro i dont have that much reputation